# Получить данные со страницы для последующего использования

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

друзья.
Для работы моей программы требуется:

1. Получить данные со страницы сайта по протоколу https (данные доступа к БД)
2. Используя эти данные подключиться к БД и получить информацию о товарах интернет-магазина

Я написал код получения данных подключения к БД (п.1)

```
        String key = "***токен***";
        String host = "https://rosfixator.ru/";
        String page = "android-mysql.html";

        URL url = null;
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStreamReader streamReader = null;
        StringBuffer  myData = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(host + page + "?key=" + key);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            myData = print_content(con);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private StringBuffer print_content(HttpsURLConnection con){
        StringBuffer myData = new StringBuffer();
        if(con!=null){

            try {
                    BufferedReader br =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String input;
                    while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                    myData.append(input);
                    }
                br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        return myData;
    }
```

При попытке выполнения программы выбрасывает исключение что-то вроде "Не могу запустить в главном потоке".
Вижу выход запуска в асинхронном режиме. 
Создал отдельный класс, расширяющем AsyncTask и код разместил в doInBackground.
Но поскольку программа запускается в асинхронном режиме, как я могу быть уверен в том, что к моменту вызова подключения к БД с использованием данных из myData, они будут доступны. 
Добавление костыля в виде задержки

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

но мне кажется это не правильно. Ведь сервер может и не ответить за 5 секунд, а значит приложение развалится.

Есть ли какой то механизм получения сигнала, что асинхронный код выполнен и данные можно использовать?

Comment: В AsyncTask есть метод onPostExecute. Он вызовется после завершения асинхронной задачи. Именно в нем и запускайте дальнейшую логику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сетевые подключения в андроиде должны выполняться в фоне.
Самый простой способ для этого - использовать AsyncTask.
Например [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php) отлично всё расписано об этом классе и как его использовать, с подробными примерами.

Вот **пример** реализации:

```
class AsyncConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, StringBuffer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Вызывается перед doInBackground и тут есть доступ к UI
    }

    @Override
    protected StringBuffer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        // Тут уже выполняем всю работу по подключению к сайту и т.п.
        // Доступа к UI здесь уже нет! (т.е. например вставить что-то в textView здесь нельзя)

        String key = "***токен***";
        String host = "https://rosfixator.ru/";
        String page = "android-mysql.html";

        URL url = null;
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStreamReader streamReader = null;
        StringBuffer  myData = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(host + page + "?key=" + key);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            myData = print_content(con);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myData;
    }

    private StringBuffer print_content(HttpsURLConnection con){
        StringBuffer myData = new StringBuffer();
        if(con!=null){

            try {
                BufferedReader br =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String input;
                while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                    myData.append(input);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return myData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StringBuffer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Работа doInBackground завершена и тут мы можем вывести результат в интерфейс.
        // Доступ к UI есть!
    }
}
```